# Select LINQ SET Attributes class

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, entity

I have two classes Product and Order.

I would like to make a select with linq that could put the value of the description of the product in an application for select

```
public class Product(){
   public int ProductId{get;set;}
   public string Description {get;set;}
}

public class Order() {   
    public int OrderId{ get; set; }
    Product _product {get;set;}
}
var resultado = from od in context.Order
                from prod in context.Product
                where od._product.ProductId.Equals(prod.ProdutoId)
                select new Order
                {
                    od._product.Description= prod.Description,
                 };
```

but this does not work

Comment: `LINQ` didn't intended to mutate data, it is for querying data.

Comment: but if I need to get the description of the product to return to a list of orders?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I can follow what you want to accomplish, but the logic above does not make sense. if you want to return the description of the products, for each order, why don't you do something like this:

```
var resultado = from od in context.Order
                select new ClientePedido
                {
                    Description= od._product.Description,
                 };
```

Comment: i need return list of order with product description , but in table order i have ProductId

Comment: Yes, in the table you can see only the id. But in you aplication, on the order, you have the actual product. That means that you have access to product description directly from order: order._product.Description. Also you can return a custom object, like it is done above, and return only the description(and order id if you need)

Comment: The problem is that I have more objects as a customer or credit card to return, which are id in the Order table, so was wondering if it is possible to return a select New Set values

Comment: If an order has a Customer and a Card, those entities should be on the order, and you should be able to access them from Order.

Answer (score 0):

instead of the class order

```
public class Order() {   
public int OrderId{ get; set; }
Product _product {get;set;}
```

}

replace with this:

```
public class Order() {   
public int OrderId{ get; set; } 
 public int ProductId{get;set;}
}
```

---

or like in mvc

```
public virtual Order _Order{get;set;}
```

and in the product class use

```
public ICollection<Product> _product{get;set;}
```